# Sql query on json data contains arraylist

Tags: java, mysql

Table - ABC

```
Record 1 -- {"count": 0, "Groups": ["PADDY TRADERS", "WHEET TRADERS", "DAL TRADERS"], "apmcId": "33500150180006", "isSent": 0, "userId": "M0000020PRFREG2015050636624494USS1"}
Record 2 -- {"count": 0, "Groups": ["X TRADERS", "Y TRADERS", "Z TRADERS"], "apmcId": "566565656", "isSent": 0, "userId": "5435435435345435435435"}
```

These are the records in ABC table, now i am querying as below to get first record as expected return but not able to do so. Pls help me for querying on records which contains list data inside.

```
"SELECT * FROM ABC WHERE data->>'Groups'->'PADDY TRADERS'";
```

Comment: are you getting an error? what exactly is the problem

Comment: please provide your table structure, rather than JSON object

Comment: your SQL Syntax looks ...interesting...

Comment: error :      org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: text -> unknown
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: i am using   key - value pair  table structure

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not yet support JSON directly, unless you are on version >= 5.7 ([see here for a nice blog post concerning JSON in mysql 5.7](http://blog.ulf-wendel.de/2013/mysql-5-7-sql-functions-for-json-udf/))

Therefore all you can do is get the field in which the JSON is stored, interpret it with the [JSON library of your choice](http://blog.takipi.com/the-ultimate-json-library-json-simple-vs-gson-vs-jackson-vs-json/) and do whatever you need doing.